# Python configparser reads comments in values

Tags: python

ConfigParser also reads comments. Why? Shouldn't this be a default thing to "ignore" inline comments?

I reproduce my problem with the following script:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("C:\\_SVN\\BMO\\Source\\Server\\PythonExecutor\\Resources\\visionapplication.ini")

for section in config.sections():
    for item in config.items(section):
        print("{}={}".format(section, item))
```

The ini file looks as follows:

```
[LPI]
reference_size_mm_width     =   30 ;mm
reference_size_mm_height    =   40 ;mm 
print_pixel_pitch_mm        =   0.03525 ; mm
eye_cascade                 =   "TBD\haarcascade_eye.xml" #
```

The output:

```
C:\_Temp>python read.py
LPI=('reference_size_mm_width', '30 ;mm')
LPI=('reference_size_mm_height', '40 ;mm')
LPI=('print_pixel_pitch_mm', '0.03525 ; mm')
LPI=('eye_cascade', '"TBD\\haarcascade_eye.xml" #')
```

I don't want to read **30 ;mm** but I want to read just the number '30'.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: Python3.7

Comment: Do not store comments. It doesn't have any meaning because 'mm' is in the parameter name too.

Comment: It's an example, not really the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hi use inline_comment_prefixes while creating configparser object check example below

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser(inline_comment_prefixes = (";",))
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) is detailed documentation.

Comment: welcome. If this solves your problem accept this as answer :)

Comment: ah sorry, almost forgot... annoying that I have to wait for 5 minutes before I can accept... I have stuff to do too ;-). Thx again though!